# Scipy sparse matrix – element-wise multiplication and division of only non-zero elements

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, time-complexity, sparse-matrix

I have three sparse matrices `A`, `B`, and `C`, and I want to compute the element-wise result of: `(A*B)/C`, i.e. element-wise multiply `A` with `B`, then element-wise divide by `C`.

Naturally, since `C` is sparse, division by zero results in most of the matrix elements set to infinity/nan. However, I am not interested in these elements since for my needs `A` is essentially a mask, and all zero indices in `A` should stay zeros in the result. In practice, scipy does calculate these items even though they could be masked if we decide that `0/0=0`.

What is the best way to avoid the redundant calculations of elements that are zeros in `A`?

Example for concreteness:

```
A = sparse.csr_matrix(np.identity(100))
B = sparse.csr_matrix(np.identity(100) * 2)
C = sparse.csr_matrix(np.identity(100) * 5)

Z = ((A*B)/C)

Z[0,0]
>>> 0.4
Z[0,1]
>>> nan
```

Required result:

```
Z[0,0]
>>> 0.4
Z[0,1]
>>> 0.0
```

Note: I am mostly interested in the performance of this operation.

Comment: If the sparsity is the same for all matrices, we can just do the math using the `data` attribute, which will be a 1d array.

Comment: That's a good point, but `data` contains explicit zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best way to do this but if `C.data` has any 0s in it they'll still come out as `NaN`. How you choose to handle this probably depends on what exactly you're doing.

```
A = sparse.csr_matrix(np.identity(100))
B = sparse.csr_matrix(np.identity(100) * 2)
C = sparse.csr_matrix(np.identity(100) * 5)

C.data = 1 / C.data

Z = A*B*C

>>> Z
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 100 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

>>> Z[0,0]
0.4
>>> Z[0,1]
0.0
```